# reading signals sent between 2 radios, serial comms

Tags: c++, mfc

I am currently reading from a reciever via the com port on my pc, reading the signals sent between 2 other radios. The problem I am having is how it is displaying to the listbox properly, as it doesnt start at the top, it puts lots of blank lines above the output, forcing me to scroll down to see it, and also that my loop is behaving strangely. 
Here is the code:

```
void Cserial_NewDlg::OnBnClickedButton1()
{
    CString tempStr;
    bool bReading = true;
    //memset(&port, 0, sizeof(port));
    //memset(buffer,0,BUFFER_SIZE);
    while(bReading) {
        ReadFile(file,&buffer[0],BUFFER_SIZE,&bytesRead,NULL); //reading opened port
        if(bytesRead == 0)
            break;
        tempStr = buffer;
        int Pos = tempStr.Find("TX",0); //finding the start of each transmission
        if(Pos > 0){/*memcpy*/} 
        else {
            memmove(processBuffer,&buffer[Pos],PROCESS_SIZE); //copying buffer to a new buffer of correct size
            m_ListBox.AddString(processBuffer); //displaying
        }
        /*if(bytesRead == PROCESS_SIZE)
            bReading = false;*/
    }
}
```

The first time the 'read' button is pressed it reads in fine, but I am having a problem with the processBuffer(29 bytes, as that is the length of the tranmission) not re-copying the data from the previous buffer(64 bytes, allowing for some overflow) after the first time round the loop, so its forcing me to press the read button again, this is not what I intended and I can't spot the problem, any ideas?

Comment: This is getting long-winded, so I'm moving it to an answer, below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Pos > 0` branch in your listing is a dead branch, but this is a problem because your else only gets executed if "TX" is at the very beginning, or not found at all.  If ever you read your buffer, and "TX" does not appear, you have a buffer read error, where you start at index -1 of buffer.

Basically, say you have a short read that doesn't return an entire message, or say you simply have an ill-formatted message that doesn't contain this "TX" key you're looking for - the CString::Find function returns -1, meaning "not found".  In those cases, you have to continue reading (maybe throw a sleep in there?) until you have found the end of your message before you add it.  This would prevent multiple button-presses.

I would encourage you to gave the details on what your expected message looks like - that will help me give more targeted advice.

Answer (score 0):

You'd be better off using a `std::deque<char>`  for your processBuffer. As the name suggests, that class is designed for a double-ended queue. You can simply append the bytes from `buffer`, and take bytes from the start.